# Animation by Scroll

Tags: animation, scroll

can someone tell me how do this this kind of by Scroll Animation?

https://radix.bio/

Would be so happy if someone can help

Best
Jeffrey

Answer (score 0):

Check the source of that page and observe data-slide-id="0" to data-slide-id="4".
Check the position of this attribute using JavaScript and change the background of page accordingly. Change background of absolutely positioned DIV based on element have these attributes (Observe Top of each element and change image).  Hope you got logic behind it.